# How do I upload a file in Selenium in PHP? Expected there to be only 1 file. There were: 0

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

According to the docs of the library I'm using, this should work, but it's not.
https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/wiki/Upload-a-file

This is the error

```
Finding ctl00_WorkSpaceContent_sourceFile
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnknownServerException' with message 'Expected there to be only 1 file. There were: 0
```

This is the code

```
echo "Finding ctl00_WorkSpaceContent_sourceFile\n";
$input = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id("ctl00_WorkSpaceContent_sourceFile"));
// set the file detector
$input->setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
// upload the file and submit the form
$input->sendKeys($file);
echo "Finding Save & Return\n";
```

This is the HTML

```
<input name="ctl00$WorkSpaceContent$sourceFile" type="file" id="ctl00_WorkSpaceContent_sourceFile" class="formrequired" size="62" onchange="javascript:this.className='formchanged';">
```

There are no results on the web for the error, not even Google. [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=selenium+PHP+Fatal+error%3A+Uncaught+exception+%27UnknownServerException%27+with+message+%27Expected+there+to+be+only+1+file.+There+were%3A+0%27), [Google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=selenium%20PHP%20Fatal%20error%3A%20Uncaught%20exception%20%27UnknownServerException%27%20with%20message%20%27Expected%20there%20to%20be%20only%201%20file.%20There%20were%3A%200%27)

I saw some related questions, but they were for sending files to remove Selenium servers. Mine is local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to send the file name as an array, despite the library giving a warning.

```
$input->sendKeys(array($file));
```

> PHP Warning:  is_file() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in /cygdrive/c/Users/Chloe/workspace/Teads/php-webdriver/lib/remote/LocalFileDetector.php on line 23

I shall update the Wiki link.